# Code Igniter + i18n multilanguages library -> redirections & SEO

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, internationalization

I am making a multi languages website with code igniter and the i18n library:

- [library page](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CodeIgniter_2.1_internationalization_i18n)
- [library discussion thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/179036/)

What's bugging me and many others on the discussion thread is that queries are redirected this way:

```
base_url -> base_url/default_language/default_controller
```

while

```
base_url/language -> base_url/language
```

It is annoying for two reasons:

1. the base url of my domain will never appear on the browser address bar (weird) nor be index by google
2. I don't want the default_controller to appear on the address bar on other languages either. So my homepage should look like:

base_url <-- default language

base_url/fr/ <-- french version

Can someone help me? The code is on the homepage of the library, mentioned earlier.

Comment: Please check out Kitlang: @[spark] (spark) or the library code itself @[github] Follow the instructions, I think it does what you desire. [spark]: http://getsparks.org/packages/kitlang/versions/HEAD/show
[github]: https://github.com/devtime-share/codeigniter-kitlang

Answer (score 0):

try to use site_url('controller/function') because the i18n change the behavior of CI an the links with base_url()/controller/funciont do not work.